# how can i hover network node attribute (using bokeh and networkx under python 3.5)

Tags: python-3.x, attributes, nodes, networkx, bokeh

i used networkx and bokeh to generate a interactive network graph. I would like the attributes of nodes hover while the mouse on the node.

I used the code

```
layout = nx.spring_layout(network,
                          k=1.1/sqrt(network.number_of_nodes()),
                          iterations=100)
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

nodes, nodes_coordinates = zip(*sorted(layout.items()))
nodes_xs, nodes_ys = list(zip(*nodes_coordinates))

nodes_source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=nodes_xs, 
                                     y=nodes_ys,
                                     name=nodes,
                                    ))
```

However, i also have some node attribute in the network data. i would like to hover those nodes attributes.
anyone can help?

Comment: Please consult the project documentation. There is a User's Guide [section on hover tools](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#hover-tool)